# Looping in user input selection

Tags: java, loops

I have made this code so that user can select A,B,C,D and then this selection is queried and the results are saved in a string which are later used in a main. What I need to do is after the user makes a selection like A and he gets the results from A, to be able to remake a selection from start instead of ending. For example I select A then queries run and I get some results in a string. Then i need something like this:

System.out.println( " Make more selections? Type Yes or No");
If Yes return to start, without losing the string values added already though.
What is the best way to achieve that?

```
    public static void query() {

    String selec ;

            boolean c=true;
            selec = user_input.next( );

            int z = Integer.parseInt(selec);
            while(c){   
                if(z==1){
                    selec="A";
                    c=false;
                }else if(z==2){
                    selec="B";
                    c=false;
                }else if(z==3){
                    selec="C";
                    c=false;
                }else if(z==4){
                    selec="D";
                    c=false;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid Choice");

                    selec = user_input.next( );
                }
            }


    if (selec=="A") {
   final String queryString =...

List<String> strA = new ArrayList<String>() ;

    }else if (selec=="B") {...

final String queryString =...

    List<String> strB = new ArrayList<String>() ;

    }else if ...
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new class.query();
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this under your if/else statements, at the bottom of your `query` function.

```
//Ask if user wants to continue and get input
System.out.println("Make more selections? Type Yes or No");
selec = user_input.next();
//If user enters 'Yes' then have them enter new selection and run query again
if(selec.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
    System.out.println("Enter next selection: ");
    query();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `do-while` loop and check the condition before continuing.

something like:

```
do{

//Here goes your code

System.out.println( " Make more selections? Type Yes or No");
//Read the input
}while(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple if statement:

```
System.out.println( " Make more selections? Type Yes or No");
//receive input

if(input.equals("Yes")) {
  query();
};
```

Place this near the end of your query method. hope that works for you.